# How to adjust a __dict__ of one class so it works in another when using type()? TypeError: descriptor doesn't apply

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to dynamically create a class with inheritance, e.g. for a Mixin.

Something like

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A', self.__dict__)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B', self.__dict__)

F = type('C', (B,), A.__dict__.copy())
F()
```

But this throws an error:

```
TypeError: descriptor '__dict__' for 'A' objects doesn't apply to 'C' object
```

Is there a way to modify a certain "owner" property of the `__dict__`, maybe detach it or some other way to solve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `A.__dict__` instead of just inheriting from `A` as well?

Comment: This question is a more MRE version of my other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678644/why-does-my-sqlalchemy-model-raise-a-typeerror-descriptor-dict-doesnt-ap I am trying to use plain SQLAlchemy models in various programs without "branding" them with the parents `Base` or `db.Model` (Flask-SQLAlchemy). Instead I want to have a factory that does the inheritance dynamically.